Телеграм бот не отвечает на нажатие кнопок, хотя, вроде, всё прописано. Python (Telebot)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def st(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'text')
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('bt1', callback_data='go in')
    btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('bt2', callback_data='go out')
    markup.row(btn1, btn2)
    btn3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('bt3', callback_data='go up')
    markup.row(btn3)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите действие:', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_message(callback):
    if callback.data == 'go in':
        bot.delete_message(callback.message.chat.id, callback.message.message_id)
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, 'some text')
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, 'Чтобы продолжить, нажмите "/resume1"')
    elif callback.data == 'go out':
        bot.delete_message(callback.message.chat.id, callback.message.message_id)
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, 'some text')
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, 'Чтобы начать заново, нажмите "/start"')
    elif callback.data == 'go up':
        bot.delete_message(callback.message.chat.id, callback.message.message_id)
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, 'some text')
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, 'Чтобы начать заново, нажмите "/start"')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['resume1'])
def st(message):
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id -1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'text')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'text')
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('batn1', callback_data1='to agr')
    markup.row(btn1)
    btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('batn2', callback_data1='to disagr')
    markup.row(btn2)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'select an action', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_message(callback):
    if callback.data1 == 'to agr':
        bot.delete_message(callback.message.chat.id, callback.message.message_id)
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, '')
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, 'Чтобы продолжить, нажмите "/resume2"')
    elif callback.data1 == 'to disagr':
        bot.delete_message(callback.message.chat.id, callback.message.message_id)
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, 'some text')
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, 'some text')
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, 'Чтобы начать, нажмите "/resume1"')

**моя проблема заключается в том, что когда происходит переход от 'resume1' к следующему блоку кода, то кнопки не работают**


Проблема заключалась в том, что вы неправильно написали аргумент, вместо callback_data, вы написали callback_data1, из-за этого в функции st() возникала ошибка.
Если заменить на callback_data, то бот продолжит работу:
    btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('batn1', callback_data='to agr')
    btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('batn2', callback_data='to disagr')


Отредактированный код:
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def st(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'text')
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('bt1', callback_data='go in')
    btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('bt2', callback_data='go out')
    markup.row(btn1, btn2)
    btn3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('bt3', callback_data='go up')
    markup.row(btn3)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите действие:', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_message(callback):
    if callback.data == 'go in':
        bot.delete_message(callback.message.chat.id, callback.message.message_id)
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, 'some text')
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, 'Чтобы продолжить, нажмите "/resume1"')
    elif callback.data == 'go out':
        bot.delete_message(callback.message.chat.id, callback.message.message_id)
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, 'some text')
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, 'Чтобы начать заново, нажмите "/start"')
    elif callback.data == 'go up':
        bot.delete_message(callback.message.chat.id, callback.message.message_id)
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, 'some text')
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, 'Чтобы начать заново, нажмите "/start"')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['resume1'])
def st(message):
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id - 1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'text')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'text')
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('batn1', callback_data='to agr')
    btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('batn2', callback_data='to disagr')
    markup.add(btn1, btn2)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'select an action', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_message(callback):
    if callback.data1 == 'to agr':
        bot.delete_message(callback.message.chat.id, callback.message.message_id)
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, '')
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, 'Чтобы продолжить, нажмите "/resume2"')
    elif callback.data1 == 'to disagr':
        bot.delete_message(callback.message.chat.id, callback.message.message_id)
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, 'some text')
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, 'some text')
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, 'Чтобы начать, нажмите "/resume1"')


Спасибо за ответ, но это не совсем то. Я изменил на более понятный свой вопрос

Увидел, приступаю к ответу.

Теперь код должен работать
